# Including empty tag in xml while using xml as target in Informatica

Tags: xml, xsd, informatica

I am using xml as target in my mapping in Informatica.Suppose there is no value for a port ,but I want to generate it as empty element in the xml file generated as .
I tried with nillable="true",but in the o/p file it is coming as .
But I want it to be :

I also tried with union operation . 
It is giving the error:
**Value not matching any of the member types in the union.**
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I session at target level there is a property named : **XML null content representation** change it to : **Tag with Empty Content** and it will generate an empty tag if there is null value from source.